# Error: Can't resolve all parameters for NoteService: (?)

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I have been following a video tutorial of angular 2 from 
http://courses.angularclass.com/courses/enrolled/73288

And the above mentioned error comes up when I run my api.

The following is the service which according to the browser has unresolved parameters

`

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
 import { ApiService } from './api';


export class NoteService{
    path: string= '/notes';
    constructor(private api: ApiService) {}
    createNote(note){
        return this.api.post(this.path, note);
    }
    getNotes(){
        return this.api.get(this.path);
    }

    completeNote(note){
        return this.api.delete(`${this.path}/${note.id}`);
    }
}`
```

and this is the api services for the webpage,

`

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Headers, Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable'; 
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

@Injectable()
export class ApiService{
    headers: Headers=new Headers({
        'Cotent-Type': 'application/json',
        Accept: 'application/json'
    });

    api_url: string = 'http://localhost:3500';

    constructor(private http: Http){

    }

    private getJson(resp: Response){
        return resp.json();
    }
    private checkForError(resp: Response): Response{
        if(resp.status >=200 && resp.status<300){
            return resp;
        }
        else{
            const error=new Error(resp.statusText);
            error['response']= resp;
            console.error(error);
            throw error;
        }
    }
    get(path: string): Observable<any>{
        return this.http.get(`${this.api_url}${path}`, this.headers)
        .map(this.checkForError)
        .catch(err=> Observable.throw(err))
        .map(this.getJson)
    } 

    post(path: string, body): Observable<any>{
        return this.http.post(
               `${this.api_url}${path}`,
               JSON.stringify(body),
               {headers: this.headers} 
        )
        .map(this.checkForError)
       .catch(err=> Observable.throw(err))
        .map(this.getJson);
    }
     delete(path: string): Observable<any>{
        return this.http.delete(`${this.api_url}${path}`, this.headers)
        .map(this.checkForError)
        .catch(err=> Observable.throw(err))
        .map(this.getJson)
    } 
}
```

`

If any other file should be included in the question then please do mention it in the comments.
Thank you.

Comment: Where did you provider `ApiService` and `NoteService`? Did you import `HttpModule`?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Injectable() // required when a service has constructor parameters 
export class NoteService{
```